# Alternative to Rand() for large database

Tags: php, mysql, sql, random

I have this query

```
$sql = mysql_query("SELECT DISTINCT a, b FROM table ORDER BY RAND() DESC limit 15");
```

Which worked great when my table has only a couple of rows, now my table has thousands this makes my page load really slow.

I have tried

```
$s = mysql_query("SELECT id FROM table");
$z = mysql_num_rows($s);
$n = rand(1,$z);
$sql = mysql_query("SELECT DISTINCT a, b FROM table limit $n, 15");
```

Which makes it a bit faster but it gives me a random row, then another 14 straight after it rather than all 15 being from random places, is there a better way to do this?

Comment: What is desired output?

Comment: Don't use mysql_ function because they are deprecated.

Comment: off topic, but please note that the `mysql_xxx()` functions are deprecated and not recommended for use any more. You should be planning to switch your code to use the PDO library instead.

Comment: @Fabio Looks like OP wants 15 records taken at random.

Comment: This [page from a simpole google search](http://www.titov.net/2005/09/21/do-not-use-order-by-rand-or-how-to-get-random-rows-from-table/) directly answers your question

Comment: It outputs 15 random rows, thats the desired output. I know mysql is deprecated we don't need reminded on every question.

Comment: You can find a really good and in-depth blog post about random select on big databases here: http://jan.kneschke.de/projects/mysql/order-by-rand/

Comment: Just repeat the `rand(1,$z)` 15 times, getting 15 random IDs, then just select them by ID. If you don't want dupicates you'll need a little extra code, but it will still be a lot faster than ODRER BY RAND() since it will be using the index on ID for fetching.

Comment: Use something like this http://pastebin.com/m6UGE37U and let me get feedback

Comment: Who voted to reopen this ? And why ?